# Split a string with letters numbers and fullstops with preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to split a large string using a delimiter like `R401.4` or `R402.3.4` using the below code:

```
<?php
  $chapter = "http://codes.iccsafe.org/app/book/content/2015-I-Codes/2015%20IRC%20HTML/Chapter%204.html";

  $data = file_get_contents($chapter);

  $split = preg_split('/(<b>[R]\d{3}[.][0-9])/' , $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

  print_r($split);
?>
```

When I run this in PHP I get an incorrect split like below, where I am getting a split where I want and after it rather than just at each `R401.` section:

> [3] => R401.2 [4] => Requirements.  Foundation construction shall be capable of accommodating all loads in accordance with Section R301 and
>   of transmitting the resulting loads to the supporting soil. Fill soils
>   that support footings and foundations shall be designed, installed and
>   tested in accordance with accepted engineering practice. Gravel fill
>   used as footings for wood and precast concrete foundations shall
>   comply with Section R403.
>
> [5] => R401.3 [6] => Drainage.  Surface drainage shall be diverted to
>   a storm sewer conveyance or other approved point of collection that
>   does not create a hazard. Lots shall be graded to drain surface water
>   away from foundation walls. The grade shall fall a minimum of 6 inches
>   (152 mm) within the first 10 feet (3048 mm).
>
> Exception: Where lot lines, walls, slopes or other physical barriers
>   prohibit 6 inches (152 mm) of fall within 10 feet (3048 mm), drains or
>   swales shall be constructed to ensure drainage away from the
>   structure. Impervious surfaces within 10 feet (3048 mm) of the
>   building foundation shall be sloped a minimum of 2 percent away from
>   the building.
>
> [7] => R401.4 [8] => Soil tests.

However when I try my expression on a regular expression testing web site like `regexer.com` it seems to work correctly.

http://regexr.com/3ds6l

Is there something wrong with my `regex` or does this have something to do with `preg_match` in `php`?

What I am looking for is for my array to be formatted like this:

> [3] => R401.2 Requirements.  Foundation construction shall be capable of accommodating all loads in accordance with Section R301 and
>   of transmitting the resulting loads to the supporting soil. Fill soils
>   that support footings and foundations shall be designed, installed and
>   tested in accordance with accepted engineering practice. Gravel fill
>   used as footings for wood and precast concrete foundations shall
>   comply with Section R403.
>
> [4] => R401.3 Drainage.  Surface drainage shall be diverted to
>   a storm sewer conveyance or other approved point of collection that
>   does not create a hazard. Lots shall be graded to drain surface water
>   away from foundation walls. The grade shall fall a minimum of 6 inches
>   (152 mm) within the first 10 feet (3048 mm).

Note: I know its generally better to parse pages using the `DOM`

Thanks.

Comment: Search about `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` *(and use the DOM)*

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using lookahead assertions as is done here: [PHP preg_split while keeping delimiter at the start of array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717137/php-preg-split-while-keeping-delimiter-at-the-start-of-array-element)

```
<?php
  $chapter = "http://codes.iccsafe.org/app/book/content/2015-I-Codes/2015%20IRC%20HTML/Chapter%204.html";

  $data = file_get_contents($chapter);

  $split = preg_split('/(?=<b>[R]\d{3}[.][0-9])/' , $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

  print_r($split);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not capturing anything, you don't need use `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`.

Here is a simplified version:

```
$data=file_get_contents('http://codes.iccsafe.org/app/book/content/2015-I-Codes/2015%20IRC%20HTML/Chapter%204.html');
$split=preg_split('/(?=<b>R\d{3}\.\d)/',$data);
var_export($split);
```

(Your provided url didn't allow access to the text, so I was unable to provide a demo/output.)